# Mysql Xampp #2002 error

Tags: mysql, xampp, mysql-error-2002

Unbelievable after everything that I have tried it still doesn't work!

I have deleted the `ibdata` and still they keep coming up!
I don't know what to do, please help!

[image: img]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only left thing to do is to format the computer and reinstall xampp.The problem cannot be found!